# The Local folder does not exist windows phone 8.1 sqlite database

Tags: c#, sqlite, windows-phone-8.1, local-storage

My app's corrupted every time I created a database. For hours finally I found the error. The local folder's path is C:\User\Def.... does not exist. So, how can I change the local folder (I think it can't be), sovle this error? Thanks a lot!

Comment: how are you creating database share the code

Comment: Within a WP app, you have to use files stored in `LocalStorage` that only your app has access to (i.e. app data), or alternatively, files that are included when the app is compiled (which is what I assume you want to do). Paths that reference files stored in these kinds of places usually use `ms-appdata:///` or something similar. Check https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh781229.aspx for more details.